# Determining the replace string based on the match in a or regex

Tags: c++, re2

I have a regex that contains an `or statement` something like `re2::RE2 regex = "(foo)|(bar)"`

Now, I want to replace all occurrences of `foo` to `bar` and all occurrences of `bar` to `foo`.

In python I can pass a function to the regex function and do the following:

```
def determine_replace_string(match: re.Match):
    if match.group(2) == "foo":
        return "bar"
    else:
        return "foo"
re.sub(regex, determine_boolean, "some texts to edit foo bar foo bar")
```

(This would give: "some texts to edit bar foo bar foo" )

How can I achieve this with RE2 library in C++?

PS: I can not use Two global replace because the second one would revert the changes done in the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest answer I can give you is this one. There is std::regex_replace but it can't swap groups. So I just use a three step swap approach.
Probably not the fastest way to do it, but quite readable (no if's)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string str{ "puzzlefoobarfoobarpuzzle" };

    str = std::regex_replace(str, std::regex("foo"), "###"); // ### some unique token 
    str = std::regex_replace(str, std::regex("bar"), "foo");
    str = std::regex_replace(str, std::regex("###"), "bar");

    assert(str == "puzzlebarfoobarfoopuzzle");
}
```